# Is there a method to find what is a good sample size for a VAR-model?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, sample-size, econometrics

This question might be way off base as I am just getting to know vector autoregressive models, but I've tried searching through the usual channels and if this actually is a valid question it might be of help to others that it is here.

Should I think in the same way about sample size for a VAR-model as for any other regression method? That is, calculate the degrees of freedom that will be used and work from there to establish what a suitable number of observations would be, or is there something else to take into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of estimating VAR(p) model for $n$-dimensional vector $X_t=(X_{1t},...,X_{nt})$ is using OLS for each equation:
\begin{align}
X_{it}=\theta_{0i}+\sum_{s=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_{sj}X_{j,t-s}+\varepsilon_{it}
\end{align}

So the answer is yes. For each equation you will need to estimate $np+1$ parameters, so the sample size is chosen as in usual regression with $np+1$ independent variables.

Things you will need to take into account is whether additional exogenous variables are included and what type of covariance matrix for $\varepsilon_t=(\varepsilon_{t1},...,\varepsilon_{tn})$ you intend to postulate. This will increase the number of parameters to be estimated.